# HTML and Web page slide shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

We have a webpage with an empty center and we would like to put there an image slideshow.

Do you know how to do that? If you do please explain to me how to do it.

I have tried a modified version of a light box, no joy and I've tried this code below

```
<div id="slider1_container" class="slider1" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
  <!-- Slides Container -->
  <div u="slides" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Trigger -->
  <script>('slider1_container');</script>
</div>
```

still no joy.

Any help would be appreciated, whether the code is JavaScript or HTML either is fine.

Comment: You could look into something like http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: @mookamafoob - save the jQuery plugins for IE9-, CSS animations will do what he wants very easily. i havent touched this site in a long time, but here is an old blog i did on it => http://lifeinthegrey.com/blog.php?id=13

Comment: If you can get away without supporting IE9, more power to you. Most don't have that luxury.

Comment: @mookamafoob - oh im not saying it doesnt need to be done, what i said was quite literal ... save javascript solutions for those that dont support it. in my blog i also have simple jQuery to perform it when its not supported, but there is no need to create the overhead unless nececssary. "throw a jQuery plugin at it" doesn't capture that context, and its important that burgeoning developers learn that early.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Bootstrap carousel at the following address. Looks to me like what you may be looking for:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

From there if you do not need the rest of the bootstrap utilities, you can just grab the carousel and configure it from here:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/